# Show error text of widget on button click

Tags: flutter

I have below code which needs to be get called on button click to show error Text, as condition failed on button click.
**Error Text:**

```
final confirmPassword = TextFormField(
      controller: widget.confirmPasswordController,
      obscureText: true,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.lock_open, color: Colors.grey),
        hintText: 'Confirm Password',
        errorText: validatePassword(widget.confirmPasswordController.text)
            ? "Password should contains more then 5 character"
            : null,
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 10.0, 20.0, 10.0),
      ),
    );
```

**Button Click:**

```
onPressed: () {
          if (validateEmail(widget.emailController.text) &&
              validatePassword(widget.passwordController.text) &&
              validatePassword(widget.confirmPasswordController.text)) {
              // launch new screen
          } else {
            // show the error text as above checks failed
          }
        }
```

How we can achive this? will setState() help us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it by use `Form` widget with **key**. Like

Declare

```
GlobalKey<FormState> _globalFormKey = GlobalKey();
```

and set it to

```
Form(
     key: _globalFormKey,
     .
     .
     .
     child: 
)
```

Here you can use `child` as `TextFormField` and write on button click failure.

```
_globalFormKey.currentState.validate()
```

For more info [Form widget](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/validation)

> ~PS: Instead of check validation out of `TextFormField`, It has own property `validator`. Search and use it.

Answer (score 0):

Using a **Form** widget.

Flutter has a good topic about it with complete examples: [Build a form with validation](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/validation)